# Performing calculations on input box

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that needs some suggestions from you folks. Example:

```
selling_price = updated cost + postage + profit + paypal + FVF;

paypal = selling_price * 0.022 + 0.3;
```

How can I solve/calculate a value that the answer is basing on the answer of the other value?
In this case, the `selling_price` value is needing the `paypal` value to generate the output and also the `paypal` value is needing the `selling_price` value to generate the output.

I found out that this one is data dependency problem. Please help me analyze this one. Any help will be much more appreciated.

Comment: Simple math. You should replace paypal like this to get the value of selling_price.
selling_price = updated cost + postage + profit + 0.022selling_price  + 0.3 + FVF;
Selling_price = (updated cost + postage + profit + 0.3 + FVF)/0.978;

Once you get the selling_price calculate the paypal value based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be more like this

```
total = updated_cost + postage + profit + FVF

paypal = total * 0.022 + 0.3

selling_price = total + paypal
```

Otherwise it would be an impossible to solve "circular logic"